# How to hide mouse's cursor if a JButton is pressed?

Tags: jbutton, mouse

Like the title says, I would like to know if there's a way to make the mouse's cursor invisible when a JButton is pressed. In my case, I'm programming a simple game and when we click on "PLAY" (JButton of my game's menu) it would be a nice thing if it disappears.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Have this class become enabled in CSS when you want to hide the mouse cursor:

```
* {cursor: none;}
```

Alternatively:

```
#div {
    cursor: url('data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAYAAAAfFcSJAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAAAJcEhZcwAADsMAAA7DAcdvqGQAAAAZdEVYdFNvZnR3YXJlAFBhaW50Lk5FVCB2My41LjbQg61aAAAADUlEQVQYV2P4//8/IwAI/QL/+TZZdwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg=='),
    url(images/blank.cur),
    none !important;
}
```

And point towards a transparent cursor.